# Paginate Atualizando Requisição?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, paginação

Bom dia, vou tentar simplificar minha dificuldade, no entanto qualquer dúvida extra eu estarei disponível para fornecer qualquer informação do código...

Tenho um filtro cujo o qual eu faço minhas pesquisas por determinados valores e ao final tenho um valor de paginate:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2 form-label">
        {{Form::label('poder', 'Poder')}}
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-10">
        {{Form::select('poder', $poder, null, ['class' => 'form-control'])}}
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2 form-label">
        {{Form::label('unidade', 'Unidade')}}
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-10">
        {{Form::select('unidade', $unidade, null, ['class' => 'form-control'])}}
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            {{Form::label('perPage', 'Deseja filtrar quantos resultados por página?', ['class' => 'pagilabel'])}}
            {{Form::number('perPage', null, ['class' => 'paginumber', 'min' => 0])}}
            {{Form::submit('Localizar', ['class' => 'btn btn-info'])}}
 </div>
```

No meu controller tenho o seguinte:

```
if ($request->poder) $query->where('orgao.poderId', $request->poder);
if ($request->unidade) $query->where('unid.id', $request->unidade);
$table = $query->paginate($request->perPage ? $request->perPage : 20);
```

Determinei um valor padrão de 20 resultados por página pelo paginate, tudo funciona perfeitamente....

Minha dificuldade é...: Quando eu mando filtrar um determinado resultado, ao mudar de página pelo paginate a requisição é cancelada e mostra todos os registros da minha respectiva tabela, como se meu filtro fosse cancelado e a página atualizada.

Minha dúvida é...: Como faço pra enviar a mesma requisição feita pelo formulário toda vez que mudar a página do paginate?

Grato desde já !

Answer (score 2):

é só adicionar com appends

```
{!! $table->appends(['poder' => $poder])->render() !!}
```

Comment: O meu tá com appends e mesmo assim não funciona, tá assim...{{$table->appends(['perPage' => $perPage])->links()}}

Comment: Resolvido...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38267498/paginate-update-request/38274616#38274616